# Not able to connect to WiFi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, networking, wifi

I spent nights trying to configure WiFi. I have edimax 7811un, RP2 with Jessie.

What is this "unassociated" issue?

Please don't post solutions older than 2016 because the newer versions of Raspbian are different. I have been through them all.

My router follows wpa-psk

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

My wpa_supplicant life

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="myssid"
        #psk="something"
        # psk=d1767cc32480efnffj81499bf877752c1550a4cd42f740d66a990accbf744364

        psk=45ed2dc498fe05646f086d66b845a4b739c4023de1549ccc6e4a8ed6c496b6b7
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

}
```

My interfaces file

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The lan network interface
iface eth0 inet manual


allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Consider this as well

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep wlan0
[    7.356938] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

The unassociated problem was solved thanks to a previous post I missed.

Now

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"bharatbusan"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 80:A1:D7:15:E9:88
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=98/100  Signal level=56/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

and

```
sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

And still when I ping to anything I get destination host unreachable. I read somewhere that maybe my gateway settings are wrong.

Comment: i also found this:  the new default network manager Wicd does not recognise this configuration. So use the wpagui manager instead, and just disable or remove wicd

Comment: *"Please dont post solutions older than 2016"* -> Note while the duplicate question is from 2015, the duplicate answer has been kept updated (edited less than a week ago).

Comment: @goldilocks thank you could you pls see my second edit as well I am still stuck with an error

Comment: @goldilocks please feel free to take a look at this [latest question of mine if possible.] (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66617/ssh-connection-fails-after-access-point-settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the line **auto wlan0** to my interfaces file just above allow hot-plug wlan0 line and **rebooted**. It worked perfectly. The other question I added in my comments, I found solution for that as well thanks to the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the solution. This will work if you add these lines to the /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```