# SSH connection fails after access point settings

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspbian-jessie, dns

I have created a hotspot or access point (using hostadp and dhcp server)  with edimax and my rp2 exactly following [this tutorial by adafruit.](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf)
This hotspot is working well, but now I want to control my RPI with SSH from computers connected to this hotspot.

When I try to connect, the connection fails (timeout).

When I type ip add show on my RPi, it shows that it has two IP addresses on wlan0:

```
192.168.42.1 - the static address I give to my router(edimax wlan0)
169.254.10.181 - I don't know how this one was set it is not in the steps too
```

*Firstly is it possible to connect to pi using the ip allocated to edimax wlan0 using ssh by connecting to the hotspot of rp? because I cant connect with any of the IPs and ethernet cable is the only way left for putty ssh connect.*

I have not been able to understand the reason. In a different question I found 
this answer a little relevant

> The origin was a conflit between two DNS servers : isc-dhcp-server &
>   udhcpd
>
> Hostapd working well, but after the connection the conflit between the
>   two servers do not permise to attributing IP to clients. And so, to
>   complete the connection.

But the problem is that in my steps I never installed this udhcpd and I dont know how to check whether it is installed or not, and if not installed then what actually is causing the problem.

**EDIT1** 
I came across this possibility as well. I am a newbie i dont know how to check for all these

> As for not being able to ssh, probably port 22 is blocked or OpenSSH
>   is not installed.

Help of any kind would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution and I thought  posting it would be a good idea if someone else faces this problem. After you finish with the adafruit tutorial (in the exact manner as stated I hope) and are not able to connect to the rp with the IP that you set while configuring hostapd (in my case 192.168.42.1)

- **sudo ifdown wlan0(change as per your interface name) //important step**
- **reboot**  //without this changes wont take place you'll see
- **check the status of dhcp server with systemctl command**

However just after completing the second step the problem should be done with.

Comment if problem persists.